# regex to replace the specific string with in image tag?

Tags: java, regex, string

i have customerText as below

```
 String customerText="TestBody <img src="test.action&attachmentId=3313&custId=456 /> Sometext @attachmentId=3313";
```

i want to replace all occurence of attachmentId=3313 (lying with in image tag) with attachmentId=3824.

So my expected output for above input is

output is

```
 "TestBody <img src="test.action&attachmentId=3824&custId=456 /> Sometext @attachmentId=3313";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `(?<=test\.action&attachmentId=)(\d+)(?=&|$|(/>)| )` to replace with `3824`

Comment: buning_legion  its not necessary that test.action will be there in img tag  just want to replace attachmentId=3313 with in img tag with
attachmentId=3824

Comment: than replace without regex

Comment: Sorry i am not well versed with regex. just want to ensure that attachmentId=3313 lies inside img tag only?

Comment: `(?<=<img[^>]+attachmentId=)(3313)(?=.+>)`

Answer (score 1):

Even if in a particular case a regex solves your problem with HTML manipulation, regexs are not the proper tools for that work. HTML is not a regular language so you better don't use regex for those tasks. Use an HTML parser. You can achieve your goal pretty easily with Jsoup:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MyJsoupExample2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputText = "<html><head></head><body><p><img src=\"test.action&attachmentId=3313&custId=456\" /></p>"
            + "<p>someText <img src=\"getCustomers.do?custCode=2&customerId=3340&param2=456\"/></p></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputText);
        Elements myImgs = doc.select("img[src*=attachmentId=3313");
        for (Element element : myImgs) {
            String src = element.attr("src");
            element.attr("src", src.replace("attachmentId=3313", "attachmentId=3824"));
        }
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
}
```

The code gets the list of `img` nodes with a `src` attribute containing your target string:

```
Elements myImgs = doc.select("img[src*=attachmentId=3313");
```

and loop over the list replacing the value of the `src` attribute with your desired value.

I know it is not as appealing as a one-line solution but believe me, it is much better than using a regex. You can find lots of threads on StackOverflow giving the same advice (including [this one :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead set on using regex, the easiest solution would be a simple String replace:

```
String customerText="TestBody <img src=\"test.action&attachmentId=3313&custId=456\" />";
String output = customerText.replace("attachmentId=3313", "attachmentId=3824");
```